# Passing an object between controller Swift

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, xcode6, storyboard

I have a storyboard which start with a login page. And I have a User class like this

```
class User {
    // Properties
    var firmCode : String
    var firmId : String
    var userId : String

    // Default Initializer
    init() {
        self.firmCode = ""
        self.firmId = ""
        self.userId = ""

    }

    // Defult Initializer with prams
    init(firmCode: String, firmId: String, userId: String) {
        self.firmCode = firmCode
        self.firmId = firmId
        self.userId = userId
    }


}
```

I am generating some values in login page, and I can create my User object with these values.

Now I want to make this object global and use this user object in all scene.

How to pass this object to other scenes? For example I want to pass this values with my object to an embed static table view controller like this

[image]

Note: Does it matter, the embed controller has a tab bar controller? I guess I need to use my delegate file?

EDIT:

Now I have created my global object like this:

```
// test value
let firmId = "Company Id"

// Creating user object without user class declaration
NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().setObject(firmId, forKey: "testFirmId")
```

And trying to get my object like this:

```
// Creating user variable in other scene by globally
let getValue : AnyObject? = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().objectForKey("testFirmId")

// checking
println(getValue!)
```

**AND done, return my value on termanal. All work until here.**

But now the value return to me as AnyObject, I need the convert it String to apply like this:

```
someLabel.text = getValue!
```

Comment: Create the user object in singleton shared instance class, which you can use anywhere in application scope. Read about that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `NSUserDefaults` for that like you can store your object this way:

```
NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().setObject(YourObject, forKey: "YouKey")
```

After that you can access it in any scene like:

```
let yourObject: AnyObject? = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().objectForKey("YouKey")
```

Hope It will help you.

**EDIT:**

`NSUserDefaults` is limited in the types it can handle: `NSData`, `NSString`, `NSNumber`, `NSDate`, `NSArray`, and `NSDictionary`. Thus no Swift objects or structs can be saved.

From the Apple `NSUserDefaults` Docs:

> A default object must be a property list, that is, an instance of (or
>   for collections a combination of instances of): NSData, NSString,
>   NSNumber, NSDate, NSArray, or NSDictionary. If you want to store any
>   other type of object, you should typically archive it to create an
>   instance of NSData.

And if you are using `NSUserDefaults` then you can directly store your instance like shown below:

```
NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().setObject(test, forKey: "firmCode")
NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().setObject(test, forKey: "firmId")
NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().setObject(test, forKey: "userId")
```

You Don't need model class for that.

Comment: I edited the question again. this works btw thanks. but now I have one more little question again. Edit: Okay, done solved it :)

Comment: You can convert it to string like `someLabel.text = "\(getValue!)`

Answer (score 0):

```
var user = User()
self.user.firmCode = 1
```

//Assign value to other variables

//Save User object in NSUserDefaults as like this

```
 User.saveUserObject(user)
```

//Function For Save User

```
 class func saveUserObject(user : User){
 let userKey = "UserData \(user.userID)"
NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().setObject(data, forKey: userKey)
}
```

//Get User Object from NSUserDefaults

```
class func getUserObject(userIDValue : NSNumber) -> User? {
    let userKey = "UserData \(userIDValue)"
    if let data = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().objectForKey(userKey) as? NSData {
        return data as? User
    }
    return nil
}
```

Comment: Hey, where did you learn to do that ?? I do not understand much of swift !! Any document that helps?

Comment: I have created Modal class for "User" module. You can get idea from this link https://www.weheartswift.com/object-oriented-programming-swift/